# Count specific character per every species of a Fasta file

Tags: bash, perl, awk, grep, fasta

I have been trying to find the amount of 1s per each species in a fasta file that looks like this:

```
>111
1100101010
>102
1110000001
```

The desired output would be:

```
>111
5
>102
4
```

I know how to get the numbers of 1s in a file with:

```
grep -c 1 file
```

My problem is that I cannot find the way to keep track of the number of 1s per each species (instead of the total in the file).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>111
11001010101110000001
```

can also be written as

```
>111
1100101010
1110000001
```

but none of the existing solutions work for the latter. This addresses that oversight:

```bash
perl -Mv5.10 -ne'
   if ( /^>/ ) {
      say $c if defined $c;
      $c = 0;
      print;
   } else {
      $c += tr/1//;
   }
   END {
      say $c if defined $c;
   }
' file.fasta
```

For both files show above, the program outputs

```
>111
9
```

Answer (score 7):

`grep -c 1` will give you the number of matching *lines*, not the total number of `1`s. You could use `grep -o` to make it print only the matching parts of each matching line on a separate line each and then `wc -l` to count the number of lines.

```bash
while read -r line
do
    if [[ ${line:0:1} == '>' ]]; then
        if [[ -n $count ]]; then
            printf "%d\n" $count
        fi
        count=0
        echo "$line"
    else
        ((count += $(grep -o 1 <<< "$line" | wc -l)))
    fi
done < fasta_file

if [[ -n $count ]]; then
    printf "%d\n" $count
fi
```

Or in pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) using parameter expansion:

```
while read -r line
do
    if [[ ${line:0:1} == '>' ]]; then
        if [[ -n $count ]]; then
            printf "%d\n" $count
        fi
        count=0
        echo "$line"
    else
        line="${line//[^1]/}"   # remove everything but 1's
        ((count += ${#line}))   # add the length of line to count
    fi
done < fasta_file

if [[ -n $count ]]; then
    printf "%d\n" $count
fi
```

A similar setup in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```perl
open my $fh, 'fasta_file' or die "$!";

my $count=-1;

while(<$fh>) {
    if(/^>/) {
        print "$count\n" unless($count == -1);
        $count = 0;
        print;
    } else {
        $count += tr/1//;
    }
}
print "$count\n" unless($count == -1);

close $fh;
```

The transliteration operator, [`tr///`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr%2F%2F%2F), will return how many transliterations it performed and since `1` is the only argument, it'll be the same as counting `1`'s.

Answer (score 6):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
/^>/ { print ; next }              # print lines starting with ">"; skip to next input line
     { print gsub(/1/,"x") }       # replace all "1" characters with dummy "x"; gsub() returns number of replacements (ie, number of "1" characters in the line)
' file
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
awk '/^>/ {print;next} {print gsub(/1/,"x")}' file
```

Collapsing into a ternary operator to determine what to `print`:

```
awk '{print ($0 ~ /^>/ ? $0 : gsub(/1/,"x"))}' file
```

These all generate:

```
>111
5
>102
4
```

Comment: The body of records of FASTA files can be spread over more than one line.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your fasta is formatted as you indicate, and assuming using `awk` would be acceptable, then the following might work:

```
while read -r one ; do 
    echo "${one}"
    read -r two
    awk -F"1" '{print NF-1}' <<< "${two}"
done <fasta.txt
```

(Note: The awk command is splitting the string by '1' and then printing the number of resulting fields minus 1)

fasta.txt:

```
>111
1100101010
>102
1110000001
```

Output:

```
>111
5
>102
4
```

Per @ikegami, if records are spread over multiple lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

fasta_file="${1:-fasta2.txt}"

while read -r line ; do 
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^\>.* ]]; then
        [[ -n "${cnt}" ]] && echo "${cnt}"
        cnt=0
        echo "${line}"
    else
       ((cnt += $(awk -F"1" '{print NF-1}' <<< "${line}") ))
    fi
done <"${fasta_file}"

[[ -n "${cnt}" ]] && echo "${cnt}"
```

Comment: The body of records of FASTA files can be spread over more than one line.

Comment: Why call the awk over and over when it could handle all this logic internally in one pass?

Comment: @PaulHodges, I am not terribly proficient with awk.  Your solution and the solution provided by anubhava are much  more elegant/efficient.

Comment: I didn't use awk for the first couple decades of my carreer, lol

Answer (score 3):

Here is `gnu-awk` solution that would work with multiline record as well:

```bash
cat file
>111
11001
01010
>102
1110000001

awk -v RS='>[0-9]+\n' 'NF {printf ORS "%s\n", gsub(/1/, "&")} {ORS=RT}' file
>111
5
>102
4
```

Answer (score 2):

To handle multiple lines of data on one header under a single instance of `awk` -

```
$: cat fasta.txt
>101
1100101010
1111111010
1100000000
>102
1110000001
>103
1100000000
1110000001


$: awk '/^>/{if(NR>1){print cnt;} print; cnt=0;} /^[01]/{ cnt+=gsub(/1/,""); } END{print cnt;}' fasta.txt
>101
15
>102
4
>103
6
```

Not as elegant as other versions here, but maybe easier to read and understand. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`.

```
awk '/^>/{print;next} {print (NF?split($0,arr,"1")-1:0)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, checking condition if line starts from `>` then print that line and `next` will skip all further statements from here. Then using `print` function where checking if `NF` is NOT NULL then using `split` function to split current line into array arr with delimiter of `1`(which will provide number of 1s present in current line, doing `-1` will give accurate count), ELSE `NF` is NOT NULL then print `0`(for EMPTY lines).

Answer (score 1):

```
mawk -F1 '$ !NF=NF - NF^/^[>]/'
gawk -F1 '$_=NF-NF ^/^>/'      # that's the most succinct
                               # vers. I could conjure up 

>111
1100101010
>102
1110000001

5
4
```

If you really want the other 2 rows ::

```
 gawk -F1 '/^>/ || $_=--NF'
 mawk -F1 '/^>/ || $!_=$_=--NF' 

>111
1100101010
>102
1110000001
 
     1  >111
     2  5
     3  >102
     4  4
```

And if you need the multiline ones :

```
gawk '$_ = sprintf("%.*s%.*s\n%.f",/^[^>]/,">", (__= index($_,ORS) ) - FS, $_,
      NF-FS-substr("",__=substr($_,FS,__))-gsub(FS,"",__))' RS='\n[>]' FS=1
```

|

```
>111                                                                 
9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '!/>/{split($0,a,"");$0=0;for(i in a)$0+=a[i]}1' fasta.txt
>111
5
>102
4

$ awk '!/>/{for(i=sum=0;i++<length;)sum+=substr($0,i,1);$0=sum}1' fasta.txt
>111
5
>102
4
```